# Why does "Galaxy Apps" require access to my contacts?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-a5, samsung-apps

"Galaxy Apps", the package manager for the <strike>bloatware</strike> pre-installed apps on my Samsung Galaxy A5 (2017), requires access to my contacts. In fact, it plain out refuses to run as long as I don't give it access:

[image]

Why does it need them?

(I decided to grant access, since I don't want any security risks due to outdated apps, but I'm still curious.)

Comment: Galaxy apps doesn't have any app that play store doesn't have. So, in my mobile, I've simply disabled it.

Comment: @WrichikBasu: And you are sure that Play Store will now keep you pre-installed Samsung apps up-to-date even though they weren't installed through Play Store?

Comment: At least in my cases, it does. For example, if Google app comes preinstalled, play store will keep it updated.

Comment: @WrichikBasu: That makes sense for Google apps, but what about the Samsung apps (E-Mail, Calendar, etc.)?

Comment: Go to the play store and try to find your apps under the installed apps section in My Apps. If they're listed there, then you can update them from there. But calender updates are never released, and I can't use their mail, so I can't comment.